# How can I find possible non-symmetric $A$ if $A^k$ is symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, symmetric-matrices, jordan-normal-form, inverse-problems

Assume $\bf A\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$

If I know ${\bf A}^k$ and that it is symmetric, how can I systematically find the $\bf A$ which are not?

---

**Own work** One approach I have considered is to assume a Jordan form:

$${\bf A}^k = ({\bf SJS}^{-1})^k$$

Now complications will arise if there are real negative eigenvalues of multiplicity 1 in ${\bf A}^k$. So let us for simplicity assume ${\bf A}^k$ has any such eigenvalue multiplicity > 1.

In the first case we can reduce the problem to finding block-matrix k:th roots on the Jordan blocks and constructing ${\bf SMJS}^{-1}$

Where the $M$ matrix is block diagonal with these k:th roots ordered to match the block-structure of $S$.

As for a minimal example $k = 2, {\bf J} = \begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ we can find all possibilities for the $2\times 2$ zero matrices by varying $\bf S$ (?)

Another example $$n=3, k=16, {\bf A}^{16} = \left[\begin{array}{lll}2&1&1\\1&2&1\\1&1&2\end{array}\right]$$

$$J = \left[\begin{array}{lll}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&4\end{array}\right], S = \left[\begin{array}{lll}0.0398278888854&0.8155246200658&0.5773502691896\\-0.7261789828314&-0.3732703464790&0.5773502691896\\0.6863510939459&-0.4422542735868&0.5773502691896\end{array}\right]$$
Then devise
$$M = \begin{bmatrix}\cos(2\pi/16)&\sin(2\pi/16)&0\\ -\sin(2\pi/16)&\cos(2\pi/16)&0\\ 0&0&1\end{bmatrix} \approx \left[\begin{array}{lll}0.924&0.383&0\\ -0.383&0.924&0\\ 0&0&1\end{array}\right]$$

This gives:

$$SMJ^{1/16}S^{-1} \approx \left[\begin{array}{lll}0.979&0.276&-0.165\\-0.165&0.979&0.276\\0.276&-0.165&0.979\end{array}\right]
 $$

Which we can verify is close to ${\bf A}^{16}$ if raised to 16.

---

Is my thinking sound?

Are there some obvious useful solutions which this approach will miss?

Answer (score 1):

There can be infinitely many solutions.  For example,
$$ \pmatrix{s & t\cr (1-s^2)/t & - s}^2 = \pmatrix{1 & 0\cr 0 & 1\cr} $$
for all $s$, $t$ with $t \ne 0$.

Comment: Yes, the $\bf M$ blocks do not need to be rotations, they can be any unitary matrix such that it's k:th power aligns.

Comment: This $A$ is not unitary unless $s^2 + t^2 = 1$.

Comment: Hmm... Yes, unitaricity is too strong a requirement, I think. Any $\bf M$ matrix which has ${\bf M}^k = \bf I$ suffices. As ${\bf A}^2 = {\bf I}, {\bf A}^{16}=({\bf A}^2)^8$ will also be so $\bf I$ can use it in place instead of the rotation block in $\bf M$ I had above.